# Why doesn't my has_many association use table_for in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

This is my image when I want show name category with association relationship:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxvIJ.png]

This is the code:

```
column :categories do |c|
  table_for c.categories.all do
    column do |category|
      link_to category.name, [ :admin, category ]
    end
  end
end
```

I don't want to use `table_for`, because it has "table" which I don't want.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply list them out:

```
index do
  column :categories do |c|
    ul do
      c.categories.each do |category|
        li link_to(category.name, [:admin, category])
      end
    end
  end
end
```